# How to do Multi-Processing (Heavy Weight Processes) using Java

Tags: java, c++, multiprocessing, exe, processbuilder

I have 2 modules one is written in Java (Web), other is in C++. Both are independent modules and deployed in Linux. I have to execute C++ (.exe files) using java. To do this I'm using ProcessBuilder and Apache-Commons  exec libraries and my next task is to make all these executions(C++) to run parallel. 
As all of these processes are heavy weight, I guess I couldn't use threads over here. Please can any one suggest me how to make these processes paralleled and get feedback for each process. One more doubt "Is it really possible with Java?", If not any suggestions to get achieve this?

Comment: You don't need threads, you already have processes that execute in parallel. What kind of feedback are you hoping from the processes? Output to stdout?

Comment: You get the threads for free; each C++ process gets an independent `main` thread. Is this question About Inter-Process Communication (IPC)? That term might help you in finding appropriate existing solutions both here on StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Comment: @Kayaman I think he's speaking about blocking wait for C++ program to execute. He wants to execute C++ program in a non-blocking way (which would allow to spawn multiple processes) and then later wait for it's execution to end.
One way this could be done is to launch multiple Java threads and call C++ program from each thread.

Comment: @BJovke `Process` doesn't block, unless you explicitly call `Process.waitFor()`.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not so familiar with Java. I've looked at the documentation for `Process` class and you're right. But that makes the question a nonsense.

Comment: @Kayaman How long does java waits for that process to get completed? In my case C++ algorithms will run for more than 10 days. Does java's process waits for that amount of time? Is it possible to get control over that process?

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at the `Process` class too. You're asking basic questions as if you hadn't even read any documentation?

Answer (score -1):

In java create a thread and execute the C++ exe file from that thread so that your java application should not wait till C++ application run properly. With the help of the thread you can execute the C++ application and your Java application will also continue loading in JVM. So put your `ProcessBuilder` codes in that thread like below.

If you want a communication between two application, you have to implement two threads one each in both the application. Both these threads will communicate through a pipe. Hence you have to implement a pipe as well.

I have similar kind of implementation like below and its works find for me:-

```
 class CppRunParallel{

  public CppRunPalallel(){

  try {
            Thread t = new Thread(new RunCppInParallel());
            t.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.fatal("GlobusMonitor encountered exception. reason : " + e); 
        }
 }

private class RunCppInParallel implements Runnable{

    public RunCppInParallel(){

      String[] command ={"\path\to\your.exe", "param"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    pb.redirectOutput(new File("\tmp\out.txt"));
        //Here in above file you will get the feed back from C++ application
    String result;
    String overall="";
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((result = br.readLine()) != null){
                overall = overall + "\n" + result;
            }
            //p.destroy();
            System.out.println(result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!! This is what I'm about to implement with Executors framework. But here what is the thread waiting period to complete the given execution task? Suppose if I do this task with multiple JVMs, then how can I maintain this inter process communication? what is the best way to know whether all executions success or not and give feedback of success and failure to front end?

Comment: @GaneshCooper, You don't need to bother about thread waiting time. Thread will wait till the C++ exe execution complete but your main java application will not wait. If you are executing with multiple JVM it will create multiple unique pipe through which you are going to communicate to your C++ application.

Comment: People downvoted because this looks like a poorly implemented example of using `ProcessBuilder` . For instance you have `p.waitFor()` which waits for the process to end, **after** that you try to read the output...which was already redirected to a file. Then you call `p.destroy()` too for some reason. This isn't good code at all.

Comment: If you see p.waitFor() is call from a thread (RunCppInParallel). Hence main java application will not wait for c++ process to end. Once you started the C++ process you don't need p anymore hence you are destroying it. Also `pb.redirectOutput(new File("\tmp\out.txt"));` this code will not write anything at this moment. You can get the detail output only when C++ process will complete. We have already this kind of code in our application and working fine.

Comment: Then how does Java knows that this process got executed successfully or not....I need feedback as well...I need processes feedback like "Future" objects in Callable.

Comment: "Once you started the C++ process you don't need p anymore hence you are destroying it.". No, calling `p.destroy()` kills the process. Luckily for you the process has already ended (because you wait for it to end) so it doesn't matter. This code is bad, and the only reason it works for you is sheer luck. I would never allow this kind of garbage in production, but I guess you have relaxed requirements for code quality.

Comment: @Kayaman, respected your comments. Modified my answer. Thanks

Comment: @GaneshCooper, You have to log some information which need to be logged in `\tmp\out.txt` and you need to check the log information from your java thread for confirmation.

Comment: Yeah..Here problem is I don't have C++ source code to check what data in logs supposed to check..Lot of image processing algorithms will be invoked in single exe file...Checking logs is not a good idea.. And I'm thinking to implement start|Progress|Stop features in GUI to invoke,progress status of algorithms and stop the process or kill the process from UI input which is making the solution more complicated as well as these processes should communicate each other..

Comment: I'm thinking to develop in such a way that even if algorithms get changed, my framework should not need any modifications. It should be like Plug and Play (Plug the algorithms and get control over that process so that i can kill or check status and display to UI)